# Creating a sticky footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/otyfw/

I'm working on a site design, and I'm trying to make a dynamic footer that stays at the bottom of the window regardless of the screen size.  Using the fixed attribute in CSS doesn't work as it doesn't scroll with the page.  I've done something similar with a floating div, however, when I tried to incorporate it with the footer, it doesn't work.  I've looked around at the other similar questions, but each of them say to add the `position: fixed` CSS rule. Any suggestions?

Edit* I made the changes everyone suggested, however, The footer it not "attaching itself to the bottom of the window.  I'm sorry I'm being such a pain with this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Robert Thompson</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/desktop.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <header></header>
            <div id="content">
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
            </div>
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #757575;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 0;
}

header, footer{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 2;
}

header{
    border-bottom: 3px inset #DDAA00;
}

footer{
    border-top: 3px outset #DDAA00;
}

#main{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content{
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    width: 70%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: See [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com); it involves wrapping all your content in a container `div` and your footer in a separate `div`.

Comment: you're using `margin-top` and `marginTop`, if you change the second one to `margin-top` it will probably work

Comment: You mean like **[this example with two changes made?](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/FwT2z/)** All that was added was `position: relative` to the body, and `position: absolute` to the footer, as well as removing your weird margin.

Comment: @Izzey Animate doesn't use dashes in their names.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use position relative, and absolute. So to your container (the body of the page) add `position: relative` and then to your footer you would add `position: absolute` no need for margining. Also look into [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) as TylerH pointed you too.

Comment: @user3542456 You're very welcome. I battled this a lot in the past, and even yesterday with some strange margin behavior (because I was using margins to begin with and not containers with padding)

Comment: I've always battled this.  I got it to work a long time ago, but it's been a while and I haven't done any CSS work in almost 18 months.  I also battle with the whole top vs margin-top rule issue.  Sometimes top works perfect and margin-top doesn't, other times margin-top works perfect and top doesn't.  It's weird.

Comment: @user3542456 Yeah the margin trick seems to be only if you use other elements that would normally push the footer down, so you reverse some of that margining.  Or use a auto margin trying to push the footer down from content above.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and edited the question, but the footer still isn't attaching itself to the bottom of the window.  Sorry I'm being such a pain with this, but could you provide some more assistance please?

Comment: Why don't you post up a fiddle like we use.

Comment: Sure thing.  I added a codepen instead of a fiddle.  Here's the link: http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/otyfw/

Comment: Seems pretty sticky in Chrome, FireFox, and Opera. You sure it's not working on your end? Have you cleared cache? Something may be odd with codepends cache handling.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE

It's a combination of the few sticky footer options out there - and some optional javascript to adjust dynamically depending on the footer's actual content (which might be different at different screen sizes)